# Передача в функцию по значению параметра rvalue

Tags: c++, c++11

Думаю, стоит сразу начать с кода:

```
#include <iostream>

class C
{
    public:

        C(int a);

        ~C();

        C(const C &rhs);

        C& operator=(const C &rhs);

        C(C &&rhs);

        C& operator=(C &&rhs);

        int _a;
};

void func(C a)
{
    std::cout << a._a << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    func(C{1});

    std::cout << "Exit" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

В классе C реализованы все автоматически генерируемые методы (конструктор, деструктор, конструкторы и опрераторы присваивания для копирования и перемещения).

Вывод дебажной информации из методов показал, что для объектов, передаваемых в функцию func (первая строка функции main), вызываются только простые конструкторы.

Возможно, вопрос покажется глупым, но для меня это стало открытием. Почему же не вызывается никакая копирующая операция? Параметры, передаваемые в функцию func, просто "становятся" локальными параметрами самой функции. Действительно ли так было всегда или же это оптимизация современных компиляторов?

Если что, я использую GNU g++ 6.3.1 с поддержкой 11 и 14 стандартов.

Comment: Было бы хорошо, если бы Вы сократили пример до [mcve], а так же добавили имеющийся вывод и тот, который Вам кажется более очевидным.

Comment: Ну, тела функций с выводом можно было бы и оставить, а вот кол-во аргументов сократить. Например, наличие `b` не несёт никакой смысловой нагрузки.

Comment: А функция func что-то делает с a и b?

Comment: @Unick как вариант, просто выводит значение параметров в стандартный поток вывода.

Comment: @Abyx ошибся я, не паникуйте :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исключение лишних копирующих/перемещающих операций обусловлено наличием так называемого [Copy/Move Elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) в языке. В доступном онлайн черновике стандарта это [п. 15.8.3](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy#elision). Он гласит, что при определённых условиях разрешается выкидывать из кода вызов копирующих/перемещающих конструкторов.

Для компиляторов gcc/clang отключение этой оптимизации может быть достигнуто за счёт ключа [`-fno-elide-constructors`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html).

Причем стоит заметить, что начиная с C++17 упомянутая оптимизация является обязательной и даже наличие ключа не приводит к появлению копирования/перемещения:

- [С++14](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2CH89smaW28jZ8B9)

  > ```
  > Default constructor   
  > Move constructor  
  > 1  
  > Destructor  
  > Destructor
  > ```
- [С++17](https://wandbox.org/permlink/h6LSgM74pDeePDyT)

  > ```
  > Default constructor
  > 1
  > Destructor
  > ```

Answer (score 2):

Компилятор просто оптимизирует такие простые классы, вплоть до интерпретации в виде простых типов.
Вот пример того, как компилятор выполняет оптимизации: [ссылка](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:1.0749542399999998,j:1,source:'class+C%0A%7B%0A++public:%0A++++C(int+a):+a_%7Ba%7D+%7B+%7D%0A++++~C()+%3D+default%3B%0A++++C(const+C%26+rhs)+%3D+default%3B%0A++++C%26+operator%3D(const+C%26+rhs)+%3D+default%3B%0A++++C(C+%26%26rhs)+%3D+default%3B%0A++++C%26+operator%3D(C+%26%26rhs)+%3D+default%3B%0A%0A++++int+a_%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0AC+foo(const+C%26+lhs,+const+C%26+rhs)%7B%0A++++return+C%7B(lhs.a_+%2B+rhs.a_)%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0AC+bar()%7B%0A++++return+foo(C%7B1%7D,+C%7B2%7D)%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:39.63222512925103,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g63,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B14+-O1',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+6.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)',t:'0')),k:29.561201375361332,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g63,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B14+-O0',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+6.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)',t:'0')),k:30.806573495387642,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

Кстати, у вас неправильно объявлены конструктор и оператор перемещения:

```
C(const C &&rhs);
C& operator=(const C &&rhs);
```

Rvalue не может быть константным, добавление const автоматически преобразует rvalue в const lvalue, т.е. вы просто два раза объявляете конструктор и оператор копирования.

Comment: Но тем не менее эти операции вызываются в нужное время. Сейчас почитаю ссылку, спасибо!