# Использование move семантики

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

Доброго времени суток!

Решил подтянуть lvalue/rvalue ссылки и столкнулся с copy/move семантикой.
Не могу понять когда вызывается move-конструкторы и операторы перемещения.

Для примера написал это:

1. Интерфейс (Foo.h):

   ```
   // class for testing rvalue and lvalue links and copy/move constructors and operator=

   class Foo{

       private:

           int _length; // just one attribure

       public:

           Foo(); // default constructor
           Foo(const int&); // constructor from length

           ~Foo(); // destructor

           Foo(Foo&); // copy constructor
           Foo(Foo&&); // move consttructor

           Foo operator+(Foo&); // the meaning is clear from the title

           Foo& operator=(Foo&); // copy =
           Foo& operator=(Foo&&); // move =

   };
   ```
2. Реализация (Foo.cpp):

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include "Foo.h"

   Foo::Foo(){
       std::cout << "\tCall Foo::Foo() -> default constructor\n";
       _length = 0;
   }

   Foo::Foo(const int& length){
       std::cout << "\tCall Foo::Foo(const int&) -> constructor\n";
       _length = length;
   }

   Foo::~Foo(){
       std::cout << "\tCall Foo::~Foo() -> destructor\n";
   }

   Foo::Foo(Foo& lvalue){
       std::cout << "\tCall Foo::Foo(Foo&) -> copy constructor\n";

       if (this != &lvalue){
           _length = lvalue._length;
       }
   }

   Foo::Foo(Foo&& rvalue){
       std::cout << "\tCall Foo:Foo(Foo&&) -> move constructor\n";

       if (this != &rvalue){
           _length = rvalue._length;
           rvalue._length = 0;
       }
   }

   Foo Foo::operator+(Foo& right){
       std::cout << "\tCall Foo+Foo\n";

       return Foo(_length + right._length);
   }

   Foo& Foo::operator=(Foo& lvalue){
       std::cout << "\tCall Foo::operator=(Foo&) -> copy =\n";

       if (this != &lvalue){
           _length = lvalue._length;
       }

       return *this;
   }

   Foo& Foo::operator=(Foo&& rvalue){
       std::cout << "\tCall Foo::operator=(Foo&) -> move =\n";

       if (this != &rvalue){
           _length = rvalue._length;
           rvalue._length = 0;
       }

       return *this;
   }
   ```

   }
3. Непосредственно вызовы (main.cpp):

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include "Foo.h"

   using namespace std;

   int main(){

       int length = 7;

       cout << "a :\n";
       Foo a;

       cout << "b :\n";
       Foo b (3);

       cout << "c :\n";
       Foo c (length);

       cout << "d :\n";
       Foo d (c);

       cout << "e :\n";
       Foo e (с + d);

       cout << "f :\n";
       Foo f = Foo(length);

       cout << "g :\n";
       Foo g = g + d;

       cout << endl;

   }
   ```

Ну и вот так собираю (Makefile):

```
bin: main.o libfoo.so
    g++ -o bin main.o -L. -lfoo -fPIC -std=c++11 -Wl,-rpath,.

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp -fPIC -std=c++11

libfoo.so: Foo.o
    g++ -shared -o libfoo.so Foo.o -fPIC -std=c++11 

Foo.o: Foo.cpp
    g++ -c Foo.cpp -fPIC -std=c++11 

clear:
    rm -f *.so *.o bin
```

4. Вывод:

   ```
   a :
       Call Foo::Foo() -> default constructor
   b :
       Call Foo::Foo(const int&) -> constructor
   c :
       Call Foo::Foo(const int&) -> constructor
   d :
       Call Foo::Foo(Foo&) -> copy constructor
   e :
       Call Foo+Foo
       Call Foo::Foo(const int&) -> constructor
   f :
       Call Foo::Foo(const int&) -> constructor
   g :
       Call Foo+Foo
       Call Foo::Foo(const int&) -> constructor

       Call Foo::~Foo() -> destructor
       Call Foo::~Foo() -> destructor
       Call Foo::~Foo() -> destructor
       Call Foo::~Foo() -> destructor
       Call Foo::~Foo() -> destructor
       Call Foo::~Foo() -> destructor
       Call Foo::~Foo() -> destructor
   ```

Возникает вопрос: почему не вызывается move-оператор и move-конструктор?
Есть догадки по поводу того, что компилятор "оптимизирует" этот момент. Однако, точно я не уверен и хотел бы спросить совета у более подкованных в этом вопросе.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Foo func()
{
    Foo result;
    if (time(0) % 2)
    {
        Foo f(1);
        return f;
    } 
    return result;
}

int main(){
    // ...
    cout << "w :\n";
    Foo w(move(g));

    cout << "x :\n";
    Foo x(func());
    // ...
}
```

Вывод:

```
w :
    Call Foo:Foo(Foo&&) -> move constructor
x :
    Call Foo::Foo() -> default constructor
    Call Foo::Foo(const int&) -> constructor
    Call Foo:Foo(Foo&&) -> move constructor
    Call Foo::~Foo() -> destructor
    Call Foo::~Foo() -> destructor
```

Функция func() такая "хитрая" чтоб компилятор не схопнул цепочку конструкторов в "return Foo()" до одного, он имеет на это право (google: c++ Copy elision)

P.S.

```
Foo e (c + d);
```

тут нет деструктора от e + d, значит компилятор соптимизировал код так, что вызвался только конструктор для "e" от int
Если оператор "+" усложнить, то компилятор не сможет так сделать. Например:

```
Foo Foo::operator+(Foo& right){
    std::cout << "\tCall Foo+Foo\n" ;

    Foo f(_length + right._length);
    if (time(0) % 2)
    {
        f._length += 1;
    }
    return std::move(f);
}
```

Вывод:

```
Call Foo+Foo
Call Foo::Foo(const int&) -> constructor
Call Foo:Foo(Foo&&) -> move constructor
Call Foo::~Foo() -> destructor
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте такую `main`:

```
Foo make()
{
    return Foo{};
}

int main()
{
    Foo x;
    Foo f(move(x));

    Foo g;
    g = make();
}
```

Пояснить, почему в остальных случаях не вызываются перемещающие функции, несложно. a,b,c - думаю, очевидно. d - тоже (копируем c, а не перемещаем). В остальных случаях срабатывает оптимизация - не создается временное значение, создается сразу конечный объект. Кстати, фокус типа

```
Foo e (e + d);
```

наводит на нехорошие мысли об UB...

*По-моему, так. (с) Пух*

Comment: Спасибо. Есть ли способ отрубить оптимизацию и выполнить код так, как я ожидаю? Просто что бы посмотреть ожидаемое поведение кода.

Comment: P.S. -O0 не очень то помогает

Comment: Эта оптимизация, насколько я помню, прописана в стандарте уже как обязательная (впрочем, лучше спросить у тех, кто стандарт знает получше). Но посмотрите решение @ffk...

Comment: @АртёмЗыктин, -fno-elide-constructors

Comment: @ixSci [не всегда помогает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/662266/176217).

Comment: @alexolut, в смысле не всегда? Всегда. То, что в C++17 поведение изменилось это совершенно другое дело.

Comment: @ixSci Так я и говорю, в c++17 не помогает, а до - помогает.