# Передача по ссылке с последующим копированием vs передача по значению

Tags: c++

Есть некий тяжёлый для копирования тип, например:

```
struct S 
{ 
    int a[100]; 
};
```

И стоит задача обработки значения переменной этого типа с возвратом изменённой копии, т.е. оригинал должен быть сохранён. Напрашиваются два подхода:

1. ```
   S test(const S& s)
   {
       S news = s;           // делаем копию
       news.a[42] = 100500;  // изменяем 
       return news;          // возвращаем
   }
   ```
2. ```
   S test(S s)               // делаем копию
   {
       s.a[42] = 100500;     // изменяем
       return s;             // возвращаем
   }
   ```

Вариант 2 выглядит более коротким с точки зрения кода, однако, как показывает [сборка](https://godbolt.org/g/G6UhMd), передача по ссылке даёт более короткий ассемблерный код.

Почему так происходит и какие есть ещё плюсы и минусы этих двух подходов, чтобы понимать, какой из них предпочесть? Может есть ещё какие-то варианты?

Comment: Очевидно, во втором случае копия делается два раза, первая при передаче в функцию, вторая - при возврате (так как нельзя вернуть копию-параметр, время жизни которой кончается с возвратом функции).

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, в первом варианте копия тоже делается два раза. Просто первый раз вручную: `S news = s;`

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, да и на счет второй копии спорно. [NRVO](http://alenacpp.blogspot.com.by/2008/02/rvo-nrvo.html), [Copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)

Comment: В первом коде сработает NRVO, так что news будет создан прямо на месте возвращаемого значения, т.е. копирования в return не будет. В случае, если NRVO не сработает, компилятор будет сначала пытаться сделать перемещение, вместо копирования (думаю, у Вас в коде S сложнее, чем в представленном). Однако во втором случае мы можем переместить объект в параметр при вызове, и переместить его при возврате, то есть избежать копирования совсем (это для случая, если объект может быть ненужным в дальнейшем).

Comment: @Croessmah, по идее с C++11 должно всегда работать. Теперь такое поведение часть стандарта

Comment: @Croessmah здесь о перемещении речи не идёт, всё-таки массив внутри никакого реального перемещения сделать не даст. По идее, описанный пример вообще ограничивается c++03, но ограничивать ответ такими рамками я не хочу, поэтому оставил только общую метку [tag:c++].

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb [только вот с c++17](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/662266/176217), а не c++11.

Comment: @alexolut, ох ты ж. Не зря я в этот вопрос зашел. Мне казалось это с 11 ввели

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, такое поведение не часть стандарта. RVO сделали обязательным (в C+17), NRVO как было так и осталось, т.е. может быть убрана копия, а может и не быть.

Comment: @alexolut тогда я бы выбрал первый вариант. Попозже посмотрю, что дает тот и другой код на асме. Так как за создание параметра функции и за место для возвращаемого значения отвечает вызывающая сторона, мне кажется, что не получится избавиться от второго копирования во втором варианте функции, во всяком случае тогда, когда она где-то в библиотеке.

Comment: @ixSci, что ж вы мне сегодня шаблоны-то рвете? То Copy ellision не в 11 стандарте, то уже NRVO не обязательно делать :( А вообще, спасибо, не знал.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, copy elision это вообще 98 стандарт, просто в C++17 ввели то, что называется «guaranteed copy elision». Хотя там реальным copy elision и не пахнет, но суть нововведения в том, что RVO стало теперь обязательной оптимизацией (правда, реально там теперь нет оптимизации, потому что копии нет в принципе). А NRVO всегда была опциональной оптимизацией, которую очень легко «сломать».

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb так во втором варианте (в ассемблерном коде по ссылке на godbolt), NRVO не сработало. Перед ret идет явный вызов memcpy. Поскольку первый вызов memcpy "за скобками" (делается вызывающей функцией), и получается двойное копирование.

Comment: В первом варианте больше контроля над моментом создания копии. Например могут быть проверены какие-то условия и выброшено исключение, до того как будет выполнено копирование.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В современном С++ более предпочтительным считается именно второй вариант. Т.е. если вы знаете, что вам в любом случае понадобится копия, то лучше чтобы эту копию для вас делал компилятор, а не вы сами.

Однако традиционное обоснование, приводящееся для этого утверждения, рассчитывает на типы, которые "тяжелы" для копирования не потому, что велики по размеру сами по себе, а потому, что требуют *глубокого* (deep) копирования. Т.е. речь идет о типах, которые являются компактными на *мелком* (shallow) уровне, но владеют дополнительными ресурсами через указатели/хендлы. Вся идея тут в том, что компилятор будет в состоянии заменить копирование на перемещение в ситуациях, когда исходное значение является временным/переместимым.

Например, если в вашем случае заменить `S` на `std::string`, то при вызове `test("abc")` второй вариант при подготовке аргументов обойдется без глубокого копирования вообще, в то время как в первом варианте вы сами безусловно выполните глубокое копирование.

(Еще более эффективным может быть вариант с двумя отдельными функциями - для параметра `const std::string &` и для параметра `std::string &&`, но если вы не пытаетесь выжать последние такты процессора, то одна функция с параметром `std::string` часто выглядит привлекательнее.)

В случае же, когда "тяжесть" объекта встроена непосредственно в сам объект, как в вашем примере, сэкономить на копировании не удастся. Я бы ожидал одинаковой производительности от обоих вариантов.

Некоторым нюансом является то, что, согласно абстрактной семантике языка, создание копии во втором варианте делается в контексте *вызывающего* кода. Некоторые реализации следуют этой семантике буквально - они выполняют создание копии и резервирование памяти для нее в контексте вызывающего кода. При этом память может резервироваться заранее, независимо от того, будет ли фактически вызываться функция в процессе выполнения. Т.е. написав, скажем, вот такую рекурсивную функцию

```
void recursive(unsigned n, const S &s)
{
  if (n > 0)
    recursive(n - 1, s);
  else
    test(s);
}
```

вы можете с удивлением обнаружить, что при использовании второго варианта функции `test` память в стеке для копии `s` выделяется на *каждом* уровне рекурсии, в то время как фактически эта память нужна только на самом дне рекурсии. Первый вариант `test` будет свободен от этого недостатка.

Другие реализации могут поступать более экономно: даже при использовании второго варианта `test` выполнять резервирование памяти только если функция действительно вызывается.

Comment: Можно какие-то ссылки/уточнение на требование языка про контекст вызывающего кода?

Comment: @alexolut: Буквально: **5.2.2/4** "[...] The initialization and destruction of each parameter occurs within the context of the calling function. [ Example: the access of the constructor, conversion functions or destructor is checked at the point of call in the calling function. If a constructor or destructor for a function parameter throws an exception, the search for a handler starts in the scope of the calling function; in particular, if the function called has a function-try-block with a handler that could handle the exception, this handler is not considered. —end example ]"

Comment: @AnT: А разве семантика обеих функций не одинакова? Почему оптимизирующий компилятор, заинлайнив оба варианта `test` в точке вызова, не создаст для этих случаев одинаковый объектный код? (Я проверял на godbolt.org, одинаковый код по факту _не_ создаётся.)

Comment: @VladD: Я попробовал вот так: https://godbolt.org/g/F4JrUD. И вижу, что заинлайненный код полностью идентичен для обоих вариантов.

Comment: @AnT: И правда :) У меня был какой-то более сложный вариант, в нём оказалось неодинаково почему-то.

Comment: «предпочтительным считается» кем считается?

Answer (score 3):

Процитирую "Совершенный код" Макконела, глава 7.5:

> **Не используйте параметры метода в качестве рабочих переменных**
>
> Использовать передаваемые в метод параметры как рабочие переменные опасно. Создайте для этой цели локальные переменные. Так, в следующем фрагменте Java кода переменная inputVal некорректно служит для хранения промежуточных результатов вычислений:

```
int Sample(int inputVal) {
    inputVal = inputVal * CurrentMultiplier( inputVal );
    inputVal = inputVal + CurrentAdder( inputVal );

    //...

    //Переменная inputVal уже не содержит входного значения. 
    return inputVal; 
}
```

> В этом фрагменте переменная inputVal вводит в заблуждение, потому что при завершении метода она больше не содержит входного значения; она содержит результат вычисления, частично основанного на входном значении, и поэтому ее имя неудачно. Если позднее вам придется задействовать первоначальное входное значение в другом месте метода, вы, вероятно, задействуйте переменную inputVal, пред полагая, что она содержит первоначальное значение, но это предположение будет ошибочным.

**ИМХО:** Это почва для ошибок. Хотя сам лично писал:

```
template<class T>
QVector<T> reversed(QVector<T> vector){
    std::reverse(vector.begin(), end.begin());
    return vector;
}
```

... и никакой вины не чувствую :)

Исходя из рассуждений Макконела разумнее передавать параметры по ссылке и делать локальную копию.

Comment: @Abyx, спросите у Маконнела. Он там старался без привязки к языку книгу писать. Потому примеры были на С++, Java и VB. Уж не знаю почему он этот пример на Java сделал

Comment: @Abyx эта книжка не о языках, а о том, как сделать свой код лучше.

Comment: Так вроде в Java нет константных параметров, отсюда и проблемы. Если на всём протяжении функции требуется иметь неизменный входной параметр, то без вариантов следует выбрать вариант с константной ссылкой. Но в общем случае такой задачи не стоит, поэтому и возникла дилемма, которая вылилась ещё в недопонимание результатов кодогенератора. Кстати, даже для варианта Java, если переменную назвать не `inputVal`, а скажем `resultVal`, как и предполагается её использовать, семантическая проблема кода исчезает.

Comment: @alexolut, ну тогда немного уточню. Разумнее всего принимать параметры как константы(не важно ссылки или значения) и делать локальные копии если надо. Так от ряда ошибок сможет защитить компилятор.

Comment: @alexolut, И да, я смотрю на это с точки зрения того, насколько удобно код читать/писать/изменять. Вы же не спрашивали именно про эффективность :).

Comment: "более короткий ассемблерный код" это именно про эффективность.

Comment: @alexolut, "какие есть ещё плюсы и минусы этих двух подходов". Я вот решил про понятность/безошибочность написать. Согласитесь, мы ж не только для компилятор а код пишем

Comment: "более короткий код" - это не всегда автоматом значит, что код будет более эффективный. Только бенчмарки.

Comment: Ну, я минусы не ставил, если Вы об этом :)

Comment: @alexolut, боже упаси:)

Comment: @KoVadim эффективность набора кода на клавиатуре: меньше ввода - лучше :)

Answer (score 3):

Первый вариант, очевидно, лучше, потому что подходит под понятие хорошего C++-кода, который [пропагандируется](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rf-in) на протяжении многих лет. Такой код не вызывает вопросов, а вот структура, переданная не по ссылке, вызывает. И чем больше размер структуры, тем больше вопросов такое решение будет вызывать. А раз вызывает вопросы, значит требует комментария. Кроме того, как Вы сами указываете в своём вопросе, эффективность двух методов Вы не измерили (размер листинга ассемблера вообще ни о чём не говорит), поэтому и ссылаться не на что.

Этот вопрос, на мой взгляд, типичный пример попытки преждевременной оптимизации, которая, в целом, может вылиться в пессимизацию с отрицательным эффектом касательно читабельности кода.

---

Написал довольно объёмный текст по данному вопросу. С ним можно ознакомиться по этой ссылке: [Передача по ссылке или по значению?](http://scrutator.me/post/2018/07/30/value_vs_reference.aspx)

Comment: Передача по значению вполне себе имеет место быть, например, в [copy-n-swap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22227972/3240681).

Comment: @alexolut, разные Tony пусть пишут как хотят. Я Вам привёл ссылку на официальные рекомендации от авторов C++.

Comment: Если Вас можно убедить только мнением авторов C++, то вот [цитата](https://herbsutter.com/2013/05/20/gotw-4-class-mechanics/) от Саттера, являющегося редактором упомянутого Вами C++ Core Guidelines: *"Prefer passing a read-only parameter by value if you’re going to make a copy of the parameter anyway, because it enables move from rvalue arguments."*

Comment: @alexolut, меня нельзя убедить авторитетом, только нормальными аргументами. Эта цитата (совет) Саттера, с моей точки зрения, ошибочна и не имеет смысла для _общего_ случая.

Comment: Саттер несколько лет назад советовал передавать по значению, позже изменил свое мнение

Comment: @Abyx, и в чём же там противоречие? Быть может я не описал всех нюансов, но противоречия там нет. Немного дополнил ответ.

Comment: @o2gy об изменении мнения он Вам при личной встрече сказал, или есть какие-то задокументированные высказывания?

Comment: @alexolut, он, как Вы могли заметить, один из двух основных редакторов CCG. Предполагаете, что он тайно против правил там описанных?

Comment: @ixSci правила CCG не описывают частный случай необходимости копирования аргумента.

Comment: @alexolut, очевидно, что правила не выделяют этого случая отдельно, потому что это не имеет смысла. Правила сделаны для того, чтобы код было легче писать и легче читать. Когда программист будет варьировать ссылку/не ссылку, в зависимости от _текущих требований_ кода, тогда код превратиться в хаос. Именно поэтому в правилах указаны два случая: `const T&` и `T&&` это два различных интерфейса, которые явно указывают свои намерения. Просто `T`, для C++ кода, выглядит плохо, за исключением частных случаев библиотечного кода (типа string_view). У Вас в вопросе довольно общий случай.

Comment: @alexolut, если тема всё ещё актуальна, то можете ознакомиться с более развёрнутым ответом, коим является статья, ссылку на которую я добавил в текст ответа.

Comment: @ixSci спасибо, почитаю. Любопытно, что только вчера смотрел на этот свой вопрос :) Кстати, у Вас в тексте встречаются какие-то типографические дефекты в нескольких местах, например [вот](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UURT.png).

Comment: @alexolut, да, про дефекты в тексте знаю, но не знаю откуда они вылазят. Т.к. они достаточно редки, я с ними и не разбирался.

Comment: Форма обратной связи на сайте [приказала долго жить](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojn8Q.png). Куда можно правки скинуть?

Comment: @alexolut, кидайте на ixsci@yandex.ru

Answer (score 3):

> передача по ссылке даёт более короткий ассемблерный код

В ассемблерном коде x86-64 clang, на который вы дали ссылку, разница между первым и вторым вариантом в следующем:

В первом варианте срабатывает оптимизация и структура копируется из переданного аргументом адреса сразу на место возвращаемого значения. При возврате не требуется дополнительных действий.

Во втором варианте такая оптимизация не применяется, и копирование структуры происходит два раза. Первый раз вызывающий код создает копию для передачи в функцию (за скобками данного кода), а второй раз - при возврате из функции.

Второй вариант длиннее на одну строку из-за оператора `lea rsi, [rsp + 16]`, который как раз и вычисляет аргумент *source* для вызова *memcpy* (в первом случае это не нужно, так как он явно передан вызывающей функцией). Таким образом, сферически в вакууме, второй вариант не эффективен, из-за двойного копирования структуры и лишнего вычисления аргумента для *memcpy*.

> какие есть ещё плюсы и минусы этих двух подходов, чтобы понимать, какой из них предпочесть?

Я полагаю, в реальных программах об этом не надо заботиться. Оптимизирующий компилятор будет рассматривать не отдельные функции, а программу в целом, и выберет лучший вариант. Хотя второй вариант теоретически "хуже", в реальности компилятор обе функции просто превратит в inline (если на них не берутся указатели), и разницы никакой не будет.

Answer (score -3):

Как вариант подойдёт

```
S* test(const S& s)
{
S *news = new S;         // создаём новый элемент
*news = s;              // делаем копию
news->a[42] = 100500;  // изменяем 
return news;          // возвращаем
}
```

Comment: эм... и чем это лучше? Я уже молчу про выделение памяти в куче где оно может быть явно лишним.

Comment: а как вы себе предсавляете работу с большими массивами без кучи? расширять стек?

Comment: раз уж такой чудо код написали, то почему не вызвать сразу копирование, а разбили на две строки?

Comment: @user278482 можем и стек расширить. Благо ключи компиляции наизусть знаю) Обычно на полгига выделяю сразу чтобы потом не думать.